Meaning of Word فرع
what does the word فرع mean in Fiqh?
It constantly appear and it is like
فرع
Imam Fulan said: (statement or hadith or athar)

The word فرع literally means "branch." The plural is فروع.
It is used in the Quran in the following verse:

Have you not considered how Allah presents an example, [making] a good word like a good tree, whose root (asl) is firmly fixed and its branches (furu') [high] in the sky? (14:24)

Like in the verse, the word فرع is often contrasted with the word أصل (pl. أصول), which means root.
These two words are used in various contexts to indicate something that is fundamental compared to something that is derived from the fundamental. Some common meanings are:

Usul ad-Deen to refer to aqidah and Furoo' ad-Din to refer to laws.

Usul al-Fiqh to refer to the study of the sources of law and how to derive fiqh and Furu' al-Fiqh to refer to the study of the actual derived laws themselves.

In Qiyas, asl to refer to the original situation which has decided law about it (e.g. drinking alcohol), and far' refers to the analogous situation on which you apply the same law as applies in the asl (e.g. marijuana), and illah refers to the shared legal cause (intoxication).

Asl to refer to an original ruling, and Far' to refer to a derived ruling.

Asl to refer to the main point, and Far' to refer to a discussion of a related point.


The fourth and fifth are probably what you encountered.
As for the fourth, many books mention some view in fiqh then mention different consequences of that view on other parts of the law.
For example, "The Hanafis don't consider taharah an inherent act of worship. They also don't require order in wudhu. A far' of that is you gain wudhu if you submerge in water for any reason even if without intention."
As for the fifth, an example is "The Shafi'is say dead animals are najis. Far' (related topic): They also say any cut-off part of a living animal is najis except for hair from halal animals, etc."

Sorry for the "spam" message but I would like to draw your attention to the Mod-election.

Since @The Z answered your inquiry from all perspectives, I would like to share a simple sketch of how such a book is usually arranged or divided.

So a book (Arabic: Kitab كتاب) is usually divided in Chapters (Arabic: Abwab plural of Bab باب), chapters on the other hand are divided in sections (Arabic Fusul plural of Fasl فصل). And sections are divided in branches (Arabic: Furu' plural of Fara' فرع) which are the subject of your inquiry.
Note: The above arrangement is just one of several possibilities that one may encounter with books of this type. Of course, this does not exclude the possibility of finding books that are arranged differently.
See also here in Arabic Wikipedia.
